# Construct of prime class is not working automaticly

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to build a basic framework for my site and to do it I need to extend the primary class, but the constructor of the primary class only working if I do the following thing - `parent::__construct()`
Here is an example:

```
class prime
{
 protected __construct()
 {
   //code
 }
}

class subPrime extends prime
{
  protected __construct()
  {
    //code
  }

}
```

Someone knows the solution?

Answer (score 3):

According to [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) parent contructor aren't called automatically:

> Note: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class
>   defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to
>   parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required.

This is correct, expected, desired and well documented behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Typically if you want to invoke the constructor of the parent class from a subclass you would do just as you suggest (parent::__construct()).  Or simply don't override the constructor method in the subclasses.

If you don;t need to change the constructor behavior in the child class, you are probably best of to not override the parent's method.

Comment: Well, I have to because I want to intilize the prime class. Btw- Mike Brant? nice name XD

Comment: I guess I don't understand.  If you are trying to instantiate a prime class object, it doesn't anything to do with the sub-class.

Comment: The sub class inherits the prime class functionality

Comment: Yes.  If you just want it to do the same constructor logic as the prime class, just don't define a constructor in the sub-class.  Doing so would cause the sub-class to execute the parent class' constructor upon trying to instantiate a sub-class object.